# Custom 404 page - does it need a 404 header?

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-404

In my project, I'm routing all requests to index.php. Then I check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` against a whitelist and display the relevent content.

Now, if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` does not match anything in my whitelist, I display some "page not found" text. In effect, it is a custom 404 error page.

My question is: do I need to write `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` before I output my HTML? What does it actually do? My error page is displayed regardless so is it important in this scenario?

Comment: If you're going to issue a 404 header then make sure that the page source is at least 512 bytes, otherwise IE's default settings will hide your page and display a "friendly" error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. That header is used by search engines, and others, to know the status of a page and act accordingly. (e.g. remove that page from their index, etc)